# C++ AVL tree recalculate height

Tags: c++, treenode, avl-tree

im working on an implimentation of an AVL tree, and im having problems with my recalculate height function. When i call it i pass in the root of the tree and a variable that has a value of 1. ive stepped through it, and found that once it gets to the while loop it preforms as expected but after that it returns to just ones. can you please look at it and see what i am doing wrong. I will post more code if neede, but i think just the function will provide you with enough information. Thanks

```
void BinaryTree::recalculate(Node *leaf, int count)
{
    if(leaf == NULL)//if we are at the root
    {
        return;//exit the function
    }

     if((leaf->getLeft() != NULL))//if we are not at the end of the subtree
    {
        recalculate(leaf->getLeft(), count);//advance to the next node and re-enter the function

    }

     if(leaf->getRight() != NULL)//if we are not at the end of the right subtree
    {
        recalculate(leaf->getRight(), count);//advance to the next node and re-enter the program
    }

    else
    {
        while(leaf->getParent() != NULL)//calculate each subtree until we are at the root
        {
            leaf = leaf->getParent();//get the parent node
                count++;//increment the height          

            if(leaf->getLeft() != NULL)//if there is an item in the left
            {

                leaf->getLeft()->setHeight(count-1);//sets the hight of the left child
            }

             if(leaf->getRight() != NULL)//if there is an item in the right
            {
             leaf->getRight()->setHeight(count -1);//sets the height of the right child

            }
        }

        return;//exit the function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is supposed to compute  the height of each subtree of a binary tree, and save that value in the root node of that subtree. You chose to follow a recursive approach, which is the standard one. In this approach, the height of both left and right subtree must be computed first, and then the highest of both is taken for the current node.

In your implementation, you use a value named `count` passed in parameter to the recursive call. What is the purpose of that value, given that we need to retrieve a count from subnodes, not pass one to them?

If you:

- remove that value from the `recalculate` parameters
- have the `recalculate` method call itself first on both children if applicable
- make the `recalculate` update the current node height from each subnode height

you should have it working. The following is a possible implementation based on this algorithm:

```
void BinaryTree::recalculate(Node *leaf) {
     int count = 0;
    if (leaf == NULL)  {
        return;
    }
    if (leaf->getLeft() == NULL && leaf->getRight() == NULL) {
        // no child, the height is 0
        setHeight(0);
        return;
    }
    if (leaf->getLeft() != NULL) {
        recalculate(leaf->getLeft());
        count = leaf->getLeft()->getHeight();
    }
    if (leaf->getRight() != NULL){
        recalculate(leaf->getRight());
        count = max(count, leaf->getRight()->getHeight());
    }
    // include leaf in the height
    setHeight(count+1);
}
```

If the `getHeight` method cannot be used, you may replace it by having `recalculate` return the height it computed.

Comment: the count variable is what i use to calculated the height of each node, i want to be able to find the lowest node in each subtree and then go from there. but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: i dont want it to recalculate the current height of the node, from what is already stored in there. in the case that i have to rotate the tree, the position of the nodes changes, and messes with that way of doing things. im thinking ill change it and use loops instead.

Comment: in a tree rotation most of the time the entire tree moves around one node, so yes i am trying to calculates the height of each node in the tree.

Comment: ah, so I was right to begin with? try my algorithm to update all the node heights in a tree.